# Drupal 8: How to get all blocks in a region to use the same template

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-blocks, drupal-regions

So what I am trying to do, is to get all the blocks in footer region to use the same template, say, `block--footer-block.html.twig`.

What I tried is to use `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()` to check where the blocks are located and add the region name to the template suggestions.

```
/**
* Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
* */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array 
$variables {
    $block = Block::load($variables['elements']);
    $region = $block->getRegion();
    $suggestions[] = 'block . '__' . $region . '__block';
}
```

Currently the `$block->getRegion();` breaks my site - no idea why. It doesn't even give any errors, the site is just blank.

Is this even a good way of doing this?

Comment: I dont think `$block->getRegion();` is breaking it. It is the next line. Take a close look at your single quotes

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that line is actually commented out in my code at the moment, it's the line before where it breaks. But you are right, there is a mistake in the quotes!

Answer (score 3):

This was answered here: 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192616/how-to-make-a-theme-hook-suggestion-for-blocks-according-to-region

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $block = Block::load($variables['elements']['#id']);
  $region = $block->getRegion();
  $suggestions[] = 'block__'.$region.'__block'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this snippet, in your `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`:

```
if (isset($variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'])) {
    $region = $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];
    $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $region;
    if (isset($variables['elements']['#configuration']['provider'])) {
      $provider = $variables['elements']['#configuration']['provider'];
      $suggestions[] = 'block__' . $region . '__' . $provider;
    }
  }
```

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/mogtofu33/fdb587329a13eedc854ef264abdd56a9)